# Calculating diff between sum of five calculations and a maximum

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a formula to find the remaining parts that can be processed in a solution.

For example, this table shows the surface area of some parts.
[image]

The solution allows a maximum processed area of 850.5 dm²

That maximum area should be decreased whenever I fill a cell value corresponding to one of the parts of that table, which is in SVPA!F6 (or the last filled row) *times* quantity of parts provided in that same sheet of the same row at column V. The maximum processed area should be decreased for all of the parts I have, which will show me what can yet be processed in that solution.

Example:
If I choose Part A (dm² = 6.06) with a quantity of 10, then Maximum processed area = 850.5 - (6.06 x 10) -> 789.9. That will give me a quantity of possible processed parts when having Maximum Processed Parts quantity = 789.9/Part Area -> Quantity allowed

The equation must go on every time column U & lastrow is the same and reset when it changes to a new value

I tried an IF statement but it became enormous and doesn't identify my solution at column U & lastrow. It went something like this

```
=IF(SVPA!F10="72-53-06",SVPA!V6*$C$24,IF(SVPA!F10="72-54-08",SVPA!V6*$C$25,IF(SVPA!F10="72-54-13",SVPA!V6*$C$26,IF(SVPA!F10="72-54-01",SVPA!V6*$C$27,IF(SVPA!F10="72-54-02",SVPA!V6*$C$28,0)))))
```

Then I tried vlookup to find the Area corresponding to selected Part, but couldn't find a way to identify my solution at column U and reset the equation whenever this cell value changes.

```
=$G$11-(VLOOKUP(SVPA!F6,Sheet1!B12:C16,2,FALSE)*SVPA!V6)
```

Edit: I managed to calculate the remaining stripped area but I cannot reset the equation whenever Column U (PAS) has its value changed in a new row.

```
=$G$11-(VLOOKUP(SVPA!F6,Equat!B12:C16,2,FALSE)*SVPA!V6)
```

Pictures for reference:

Sheet SVPA, where the values are inserted (main form)

[image]

Sheet Equat, where the equations are:

[image]

Comment: Without a screenshot of the area where you're selecting parts and numbers of parts, it's difficult to follow exactly what your process looks like.

Comment: Apologies. Eddited and added images